# como pasar una variable de js a php

Tags: php, javascript

Hola buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código que me carga unos registros, pero también lo que me gustaría es pasar una variable aprovechando el código.

```
<script >
   var mivariable=1;
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#concepto").load('carga.php');

   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En js puedes concatenar variables usando el operador `+`. Prueba lo siguiente:

```
...
$("#concepto").load('carga.php?variable='+variable);
...
```

Después en tu archivo php puedes usarla con `$_GET['variable]`

```php
$miVar = $_GET['variable];
```

Comment: Gracias eso era exactamente lo que requeria